# Jboss standalone-full.xml file getting overridden while restart

Tags: jboss

I have modified the standalone-full.xml while jboss is running. And then I have restarted the jboss instance. My change is not available in the file (standalone-full.xml) after restarting. Seems, previous version (before modification) got restored. 
But sometimes, changes are reflecting after restarting. 
Its confusing. Any Idea, what is happening while restart?

Comment: Are you sure there is no JBoss management solution which is able to detect configuration changes and override them? I've not used drift detection in JON/RHQ but I'd guess it is possible to revert to old config that way. As the configuration scanning interval might be rather long, sometimes your changes might get detected before restart, sometimes they might not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have modified the standalone-full.xml while jboss is running.

JBoss actively manages the server configuration, and rewrites the XML based on events that take place during its operation. I am assuming that you made these modifications by editing the XML directly using a text editor. While you can do this with little impact while the server is offline, doing this while the server is running yields unpredictable results, as you have found.

You can definitely make changes to the server's configuration while it is running, but for it to be consistently applied you should use the web management console (http://localhost:8080/console) or the CLI (`${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh`). Making your changes this way, you can even get feedback on whether your change will require the restart of JBoss.